# Getting overall disc size needed by install (all stuff at "Files" section)

Tags: inno-setup

I faced problem of getting overall size of installation, and found it , eh, surprisingly difficult.

I have some files at "Files" section, and I'm checking is there is enough free space in a chosen directory. The problem is that is looks like some parts pf it are directories with subdirectories in them.

```
"Source: ".\Files\*";"
```

feels like I need a recursion function FindFirst/FindNext but It would be a loop over all Entities of [Files] section running a recursion func for each... It would be easier to just add needed functutionality to Inno, something like NeededSpace function.

So I wonder maybe there is a easy way of doung this? Seems like a common need, right?

Comment: There is no direct way, and yes, quite a lot of people asks for this feature. As a workaround I would think of a constant whose value you will fill by the preprocessor.

Comment: @TLama : I thought about adding define and passing value from outside before compiling, but my teamcity already have 19 steps, no more steps + I dont like pyton. I'll add some function to Inno. Yerstarday I already added InitLanguageDialog + some other stuff that I used from Extended chinese version like mouseevents and stuff to my Inno fork :) But still I would have save myself a tons of time if I just went for writing custom install without Inno I guess :((( #hateInno

Comment: Preprocessor has `FindFirst`, `FindNext` and `FileSize` functions, so even preprocessor could do that.